# Count how many times each value is repeated in an array

Tags: iphone, ios6

How to check that how many time items are repeated in array. I am having an array that contains repetitive item. Below is array.

```
"Family:0",
"Family:0",
"Family:0",
"Gold:3",
"Gold:3"
```

So, i want in response values 3 and 2 for respective items. How can i achieve that. Hope i made my point clear. If any thing not clear please ask.

Below is my code i tried.

```
int occurrences = 0;
int i=0;
for(NSString *string in arrTotRows){
    occurrences += ([string isEqualToString:[arrTotRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]); //certain object is @"Apple"
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. Add all your objects to a counted set, then use the `countForObject:` method to find out how often each object appears.

Example

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Family:0", @"Family:0", @"Gold:3", @"Gold:3", nil];
    NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:names];

    for (id item in set)
    {
        NSLog(@"Name=%@, Count=%lu", item, (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item]);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Name=Gold:3, Count=2

Name=Family:0, Count=2
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:yourArray];
```

For getting the number of occurrences:

```
int objectCount = [countedSet countForObject:yourQuery];
```

(where `yourQuery` is the object whose multiplicity you want to get). In your case, for example:

```
int objectCount = [countedSet countForObject:@"Family:0"];
```

and `objectCount` should be equal to 3 because "Family:0" is three times in the multiset.

Comment: @iPhoneProgrammatically Any object in your multiset. For example: `"Family:0"`, and it should return 3. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) solves this very problem.  Add all of the strings with `addObject:` and then get the final counts with `countForObject:` as you enumerate the set.

Answer (score 0):

please try this....

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.count; ++i) {
    NSString *string = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    for (int j = i+1; j < array.count; ++j) {
        if ([string isEqualToString:[array objectAtIndex:j]]) {
         count++;
        }
    }
```